# Training model to recognize brands as entities

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to create a model in LUIS that allow me to detect if a brand (any brand) is mentioned in an utterance. I've tried different approaches but I'm struggling to get it working.

First I have an intent `searchBrand` with some examples utterances:

```
'Help me find info about Channel'
'I want to know more about Adidas'
...
```

What I want is that LUIS recognizes that a brand has been mentioned in the utterance (as an entity).
I believe I have these options:

1. Use a List Entity: impossible since I would have to fill the list
   with every possible brand that exists and, moreover, the user would
   have to write the brand exactly as it is, not allowing typos (e.g. ralf
   lauren)
2. Use a ML Entity: I believe this could be the right approach. I've tried the following without success:

   - Create a ML Entity "brands"
   - Add a Structure with 1 component "brand"
   - Add to the component a Descriptor with a list of different brands as an example

Once I label the entities in the utterances, the model recognizes correctly the brands that I added to the Descriptor but it fails to recognize others brands or typos

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of how the model is recognizing the ML entities?

Comment: I'm adding my solution with a screenshot since I got it working. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working following this:

1. Create a ML Entity "brands"
2. Add to the entity a Descriptor with a list of different brands as an example. Remember to **normalize** the elements in the Descriptor
3. Add brands to the Descriptor
4. Label entities as "brands" inside utterances in intent "searchBrands"
5. Train & test the model

It is very important to **normalize** everything in LUIS. I had the brands inside the Descriptor capitalized and LUIS couldn't recognize new ones, once I normalized the brands LUIS started suggesting new ones and recognizing more when testing the model

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a pattern entity. It fits somewhere between the two options you listed. You do need to train it with the patterns, and if the pattern is off at all it will not recognize the entity (and won't recognize the intent either unless you've separately trained it with utterances, which you should). However, it seems like the phrasings in your case would be consistent enough that you could define a few patterns for this, and as you train your bot from endpoint utterances you can add additional patterns as needed. Here is an example:

[image: LUIS Pattern Training and Testing]

As I put this together I realized I'm ignoring [help me] and [find], essentially the pattern is "info about {brand}", which may or may not be appropriate depending on your other intents. If you say something different like "Tell me more about Adidas", the intent will be recognized (I trained it with your sample utterances), but the pattern, and therefore entity, will not.

[Tutorial on using Patterns in LUIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-pattern)

Comment: Thanks @billoverton ! Very clever solution, although I've tried it and it doesn't solve my problem since my utterances are more complex than the examples I used here, so it is difficult to implement patterns...